# Hexadecimal string to character?

Tags: c#

Given a string like `"5A"` I want to get the character represented by that hexadecimal value. In this case, `Z`. How would I do that?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

How about something like

```
char charVal = (char)int.Parse("5A", NumberStyles.AllowHexSpecifier);
```